# numpy: efficiently add rows of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a matrix.

```
mat = array([
   [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11]
   ])
```

I'd like to get the sum of the rows at certain indices: eg.

```
ixs = np.array([0,2,0,0,0,1,1])
```

I know I can compute the answer as:

```
mat[ixs].sum(axis=0)
> array([16, 23, 30, 37])
```

The problem is ixs may be very long, and I don't want to use all the memory to create the intermediate product mat[ixs], only to reduce it again with the sum.

I also know I could simply count up the indices and use multiplication instead.

```
np.bincount(ixs, minlength=mat.shape[0).dot(mat)
> array([16, 23, 30, 37])
```

But that will be expensive if my ixs are sparse.

I know about scipy's sparse matrices, and I suppose I could use them, but I'd prefer a pure numpy solution as sparse matrices are limited in various ways (such as only being 2-d)

So, is there a pure numpy way to merge the indexing and sum-reduction in this case?

## Conclusions:

Thanks you Divakar and hpaulj for your very thorough responses.  By "sparse" I meant that most of the values in `range(w.shape[0])` are not in ixs.  Using that new definition (and with more realisitic data size, I re-ran Divakar tests, with some new funcitona dded :

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(1234)
mat = rng.randn(1000, 500)
ixs = rng.choice(rng.randint(mat.shape[0], size=mat.shape[0]/10), size=1000)

# Divakar's solutions
In[42]: %timeit org_indexing_app(mat, ixs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
In[43]: %timeit org_bincount_app(mat, ixs)
The slowest run took 4.07 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 177 µs per loop
In[44]: %timeit indexing_modified_app(mat, ixs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop
In[45]: %timeit bincount_modified_app(mat, ixs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 258 µs per loop
In[46]: %timeit simply_indexing_app(mat, ixs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop
In[47]: %timeit take_app(mat, ixs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
In[48]: %timeit unq_mask_einsum_app(mat, ixs)
10 loops, best of 3: 58.2 ms per loop 
# hpaulj's solutions
In[53]: %timeit hpauljs_sparse_solution(mat, ixs)
The slowest run took 9.34 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 524 µs per loop
%timeit hpauljs_second_sparse_solution(mat, ixs)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.91 ms per loop
# Sparse version of original bincount solution (see below):
In[60]: %timeit sparse_bincount(mat, ixs)
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.7 µs per loop
```

**The winner** in this case is the sparse version of the bincount solution.

```
def sparse_bincount(mat, ixs):
    x = np.bincount(ixs)
    nonzeros, = np.nonzero(x)
    x[nonzeros].dot(mat[nonzeros])
```

Comment: By *sparsey* `ixs`, do you mean lots of `zeors` in it or something else?

Comment: I mean most most of the values in `range(w.shape[0])` are not in ixs

Comment: In other words  `np.bincount(ixs, minlength=mat.shape[0)` can be sparse

Comment: Alright, for such a case take a look at : `bincount_modified_app` approach posted in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are assuming that `ixs` could be *sparsey*, we could modify the strategy to get the summations of rows from the `zero-th` row and rest of the rows separately based on the given row indices. So, we could use the `bincount` method for the `non-zero-th` indexed rows summation and add it with the `(zero-th row x no. of zeros` in `ixs`).

Thus, the second approach could be modified, like so -

```
nzmask = ixs!=0
nzsum = np.bincount(ixs[nzmask]-1, minlength=mat.shape[0]-1).dot(mat[1:])
row0_sum = mat[0]*(len(ixs) - np.count_nonzero(nzmask))
out = nzsum + row0_sum
```

We could extend this strategy to the first approach as well, like so -

```
out = mat[0]*(len(ixs) - len(nzidx)) + mat[ixs[nzidx]].sum(axis=0)
```

If we are working with lots of non-zero indices that are repeated, we could alternatively make use of `np.take` with focus on performance. Thus, `mat[ixs[nzidx]]` could be replaced by `np.take(mat,ixs[nzidx],axis=0)` and similarly `mat[ixs]` by `np.take(mat,ixs,axis=0)`. With such repeated indices based indexing `np.take` brings out some noticeable speedup as compared to simply indexing.

Finally, we could use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to perform these row ID based selection and summing, like so -

```
nzmask = ixs!=0
unq,tags = np.unique(ixs[nzmask],return_inverse=1)
nzsum = np.einsum('ji,jk->k',np.arange(len(unq))[:,None] == tags,mat[unq])
out = mat[0]*(len(ixs) - np.count_nonzero(nzmask)) + nzsum
```

### Benchmarking

Let's list out all the five approaches posted thus far in this post and also include the two approaches posted in the question for some runtime testing as functions -

```
def org_indexing_app(mat,ixs):
    return mat[ixs].sum(axis=0)

def org_bincount_app(mat,ixs):
    return np.bincount(ixs, minlength=mat.shape[0]).dot(mat)

def indexing_modified_app(mat,ixs):
    return np.take(mat,ixs,axis=0).sum(axis=0)

def bincount_modified_app(mat,ixs):
    nzmask = ixs!=0
    nzsum = np.bincount(ixs[nzmask]-1, minlength=mat.shape[0]-1).dot(mat[1:])
    row0_sum = mat[0]*(len(ixs) - np.count_nonzero(nzmask))
    return nzsum + row0_sum

def simply_indexing_app(mat,ixs):
    nzmask = ixs!=0
    nzsum = mat[ixs[nzmask]].sum(axis=0)
    return mat[0]*(len(ixs) - np.count_nonzero(nzmask)) + nzsum

def take_app(mat,ixs):
    nzmask = ixs!=0
    nzsum = np.take(mat,ixs[nzmask],axis=0).sum(axis=0)
    return mat[0]*(len(ixs) - np.count_nonzero(nzmask)) + nzsum

def unq_mask_einsum_app(mat,ixs):
    nzmask = ixs!=0
    unq,tags = np.unique(ixs[nzmask],return_inverse=1)
    nzsum = np.einsum('ji,jk->k',np.arange(len(unq))[:,None] == tags,mat[unq])
    return mat[0]*(len(ixs) - np.count_nonzero(nzmask)) + nzsum
```

**Timings**

Case #1 (`ixs` is 95% sparsey) :

```
In [301]: # Setup input
     ...: mat = np.random.rand(20,4)
     ...: ixs = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000))
     ...: ixs[np.random.rand(ixs.size)<0.95] = 0 # Make it approx 95% sparsey
     ...: 

In [302]: # Timings
     ...: %timeit org_indexing_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit org_bincount_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit indexing_modified_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit bincount_modified_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit simply_indexing_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit take_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit unq_mask_einsum_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.89 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 428 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.29 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 329 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 537 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 462 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
```

Case #2 (`ixs` is 98% sparsey) :

```
In [303]: # Setup input
     ...: mat = np.random.rand(20,4)
     ...: ixs = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000))
     ...: ixs[np.random.rand(ixs.size)<0.98] = 0 # Make it approx 98% sparsey
     ...: 

In [304]: # Timings
     ...: %timeit org_indexing_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit org_bincount_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit indexing_modified_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit bincount_modified_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit simply_indexing_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit take_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: %timeit unq_mask_einsum_app(mat,ixs)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.86 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 438 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.5 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 260 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 318 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 288 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 694 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `bincount` is `add.at`:

```
In [193]: mat
Out[193]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [194]: ixs
Out[194]: array([0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

In [195]: J = np.zeros(mat.shape[0],int)
In [196]: np.add.at(J, ixs, 1)
In [197]: J
Out[197]: array([4, 2, 1])

In [198]: np.dot(J, mat)
Out[198]: array([16, 23, 30, 37])
```

By the sparsity, you mean, I assume, that `ixs` might not include all the rows, for example, `ixs` without the 0s:

```
In [199]: ixs = np.array([2,1,1])
In [200]: J=np.zeros(mat.shape[0],int)
In [201]: np.add.at(J, ixs, 1)
In [202]: J
Out[202]: array([0, 2, 1])
In [203]: np.dot(J, mat)
Out[203]: array([16, 19, 22, 25])
```

`J` still has the `mat.shape[0]` shape.  But the `add.at` should scale as the length of `ixs`.

A sparse solution would look something like:

Make a sparse matrix from `ixs` that looks like:

```
In [204]: I
Out[204]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

sum the rows; sparse does this with matrix multiplication like:

```
In [205]: np.dot(I, np.ones((7,),int))
Out[205]: array([4, 2, 1])
```

then do our dot:

```
In [206]: np.dot(np.dot(I, np.ones((7,),int)), mat)
Out[206]: array([16, 23, 30, 37])
```

Or in sparse code:

```
In [225]: J = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(ixs,int),(np.arange(ixs.shape[0]), ixs)))
In [226]: J.A
Out[226]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
In [227]: J.sum(axis=0)*mat
Out[227]: matrix([[16, 23, 30, 37]])
```

`sparse`, when converting from `coo` to `csr` sums duplicates.  I can take advantage that with

```
In [229]: J = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(ixs,int), (np.zeros_like(ixs,int), ixs)))
In [230]: J
Out[230]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 7 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [231]: J.A
Out[231]: array([[4, 2, 1]])
In [232]: J*mat
Out[232]: array([[16, 23, 30, 37]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

After much number crunching (see Conclusions of original Question), the best-performing answer, when the inputs are defined as follows:

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(1234)
mat = rng.randn(1000, 500)
ixs = rng.choice(rng.randint(mat.shape[0], size=mat.shape[0]/10), size=1000)
```

Seems to be:

```
def sparse_bincount(mat, ixs):
    x = np.bincount(ixs)
    nonzeros, = np.nonzero(x)
    x[nonzeros].dot(mat[nonzeros])
```